# function that returns prime index characters in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to select the characters from a string whose indexes correspond to prime numbers between 1 and 100 and return them in an array. So for example, if my input is "abcdefghijklm" the function should return ["c", "d", "f", "h", "l", "n"] since "c" corresponds to index 2 (2 = prime number), "d" corresponds to index 3 (3 = prime number) etc.

Here's my code:

```
function primeChars (string) {
  if (string.length <= 1) {
    return "empty string";
  }
  var primeIdx = [];
  var res = []; 
  for (var val = 0; val <= 100; val++) {
    var notPrime = false;
    for (var i = 2; i <= val; i++) {
      if (val%i===0 && i!==val) {
        notPrime = true;
      }
    }
    if (notPrime === false) {
      primeIdx.push(val);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < primeIdx.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <string.length; j++) {
      if (i === j) {
        return res.push(string[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem is and/or ask a question. You only said what your end goal was.

Comment: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/pbj6x1u4/2/

Comment: apologies, the problem is quite simply that my code doesn't work the way I intend it to. It only returns a single number instead of an array of characters. I'd just be interested to know why...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  getArrayPrime('ABCDEFGHIJLM');  
});

function getArrayPrime(myString){
    var resultArray = [];

    for(var i=0;i<myString.length;i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
        resultArray.push(myString[i]);
      }
    } 
        console.info('resultArray:',resultArray);
}

function isPrime(value) {
    for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return value > 1;
}
```

Comment: Simply posting alternative code isn't helpful. A good answer will explain the OPs issue and how to fix it. Also, there is no value above `value/2` that can possibly be a factor, so there is no point in testing higher.

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments to improve your current code. Please feel free to ask any doubt.

```
function primeChars (string) {
  //Why string.length <= 1 it should be 0. Even string with 1 char possible.

  if (string.length <=  1) {
    return "empty string";
  }

  var primeIdx = [];
  var res = []; 

  //Why we need to find all primeindexes instead try to find prime indexes max upto string length or if string length > 100 then upto 100.

  for (var val = 0; val <= 100; val++) {
    var notPrime = false;

    //can run this loop upto i< val and can avoid checking of i !== val

    for (var i = 2; i <= val; i++) {
      if (val%i===0 && i!==val) {
        notPrime = true;
      }
    }
    //if we will run it upto string length no need to store prime indexes just get data at those index and you are done.
    //res.push(string[val])
    if (notPrime === false) {
      primeIdx.push(val);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < primeIdx.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <string.length; j++) {
      if (i === j) {
        return res.push(string[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply posting alternative code isn't helpful. A good answer will explain the OPs issue and how to fix it.